# Taking out the plank from one's own eye

Tags: personal-practice, reference-request, virtue

Is there any equivalent quotation from the Buddhist scriptures to the following from the Christian Bible ([Matthew 7:3-5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%207%3A3-5&version=NIV))?

> Why do you look at the speck of sawdust in your brother’s eye and pay
>   no attention to the plank in your own eye? How can you say to your
>   brother, ‘Let me take the speck out of your eye,’ when all the time
>   there is a plank in your own eye? You hypocrite, first take the
>   plank out of your own eye, and then you will see clearly to remove the
>   speck from your brother’s eye.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SN 55.7; MN 8; Dhp 158-159; MN 40

> 158. One should first establish oneself in what is proper; then only should one instruct others. Thus the wise man will not be reproached.
> 159. One should do what one teaches others to do; if one would train others, one should be well controlled oneself. Difficult, indeed, is
>        self-control.
>
>      ---
>
> SN 55.7  Since I dislike this thing, how can I inflict it on someone else?

Answer (score 2):

> So then the bamboo acrobat said this to his assistant Medakathalika:
>   "You look after me, my dear Medakathalika, and I'll look after you.
>   Thus with us looking after one another, guarding one another,
>   we'll show off our craft, receive some payment,
>   and safely climb down the bamboo pole."
>
> This being said, the assistant Medakathalika said this to the bamboo acrobat:
>   "That will not do at all, master!
>   You look after yourself, master, and I will look after myself.
>   Thus with each of us looking after ourselves, guarding ourselves,
>   we'll show off our craft, receive some payment,
>   and safely climb down from the bamboo pole.
>   That's the right way to do it!" ~~ [SN 47.19](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn47/sn47.019.olen.html) ~~

Answer (score 1):

From [Dhammapada 50](https://www.tipitaka.net/tipitaka/dhp/verseload.php?verse=050):

> Verse 50: One should not consider the faults of others, nor their
> doing or not doing good or bad deeds. One should consider only whether
> one has done or not done good or bad deeds.

Alternative translation from [here](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/dhp/dhp.04.budd.html):

> 50. Let none find fault with others; let none see the omissions and commissions of others. But let one see one's own acts, done and
>     undone.

The commentary states:

> The Story of the Ascetic Paveyya
>
> While residing at the Jetavana monastery, the Buddha uttered Verse
> (50) of this book, with reference to the ascetic Paveyya and a rich
> lady.
>
> A rich lady of Savatthi had adopted Paveyya, an ascetic, as a son and
> was looking after his needs. When she heard her neighbours talking in
> praise of the Buddha, she wished very much to invite him to her house
> to offer him alms-food. So, the Buddha was invited and choice food was
> offered. As the Buddha was expressing appreciation (anumodana),
> Paveyya, who was in the next room, fumed with rage. He blamed and
> cursed the lady for venerating the Buddha. The lady heard him cursing
> and shouting and felt so ashamed that she could not concentrate on
> what the Buddha was saying. The Buddha told her not to be concerned
> about those curses and threats, but to concentrate only on her own
> good and bad deeds.
>
> Then the Buddha spoke in verse as follows:
>
> Verse 50: One should not consider the faults of others, nor their
> doing or not doing good or bad deeds. One should consider only whether
> one has done or not done good or bad deeds.
>
> At the end of the discourse the rich lady attained Sotapatti Fruition.

---

From [Dhammapada 252](https://www.tipitaka.net/tipitaka/dhp/verseload.php?verse=252):

> Verse 252: It is easy to see the faults of others, but difficult to
> see one's own. A man broadcasts the fault; of others like winnowing
> chaff in the wind, but hides his own faults as a crafty fowler covers
> himself.

The commentary states:

> The Story of Mendaka the Rich Man
>
> While residing near the town of Baddiya, the Buddha uttered Verse
> (252) of this book with reference to the renowned rich man Mendaka and
> his family.
>
> Once, during his tour of Anga and Uttara regions, the Buddha saw in
> his vision that time was ripe for Mendaka, his wife, his son, his
> daughter-in-law, his granddaughter and his servant, to attain
> Sotapatti Fruition. Seeing the prospect of these six people attaining
> Sotapatti Fruition, the Buddha went to the town of Baddiya.
>
> Mendaka was an extremely rich man. It was said that he found a large
> number of life-size golden statues of goats in his backyard. For this
> reason, he was known as Mendaka (a goat) the rich man. Again, it was
> also said that during the time of Vipassi Buddha he had donated a
> monastery for Vipassi Buddha and a congregation hall complete with a
> platform for the preacher. On completion of these buildings he made
> offerings of alms-food to Vipassi Buddha and the bhikkhus for four
> months. Then, in yet another of his past existences, when he was a
> rich man in Baranasi, there was a famine throughout the region. One
> day, they had cooked a meal just enough for the members of the family
> when a paccekabuddha stood at the door for alms-food. Then and there
> he offered all the food. But due to his great faith and generosity,
> the rice pot was later found to be miraculously filled up again; so
> also were his granaries.
>
> Mendaka and his family, hearing that the Buddha was coming to Baddiya,
> went to pay homage to him. After hearing the discourse given by the
> Buddha, Mendaka, his wife Candapaduma, his son Danancaya, his
> daughter-in-law Sumanadevi, his granddaughter Visakha and the servant
> Punna attained Sotapatti Fruition. Mendaka then told the Buddha how on
> his way, some ascetics had spoken ill of the Buddha and had tried to
> dissuade him from coming to see him. The Buddha then said, "My
> disciple, it is natural for people not to see one's own faults, and to
> exaggerate other people's faults and failings."
>
> Then the Buddha spoke in verse as follows:
>
> Verse 252: It is easy to see the faults of others, but difficult to
> see one's own. A man broadcasts the fault; of others like winnowing
> chaff in the wind, but hides his own faults as a crafty fowler covers
> himself.

Answer (score 0):

```
Regard him as one who
       points out
       treasure,
the wise one who
seeing your faults
       rebukes you.
Stay with this sort of sage.
For the one who stays
with a sage of this sort,
       things get better,
       not worse.

Let him admonish, instruct,
    deflect you
away from poor manners.
To the good, he's endearing;
to the bad, he's not.
```

[Panditavagga](https://sangham.net/en/tipitaka/sut/kn/dhp/dhp.06.than)

*[Not given for stacks, exchange, world-binding trades but as gift for an escape frim this wheel]*